# Provide a condition for a monomial to divide a product of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the polynomial ring $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ over the field $K,$ I need to check the following: $$w \cdot \frac{v}{\gcd(u,v)} = w' \cdot \frac{u}{\gcd(u,v)} \implies \frac{u}{\gcd(u,v)} | w,$$ whereby $u, v$ are monomials in $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ and $\gcd(u,v)$ is the greatest common divisor of $u$ and $v,$ and $w, w'$ are polynomials from the polynomial ring. As $\gcd(u,v)$ divides both $u$ and $v,$ in case $u = \gcd(u,v),$ then $u | v$ and thus $\frac{u}{\gcd(u,v)} | \frac{v}{\gcd(u,v)}.$ But this must not be the case in general. For example in $K[X,Y,Z]$ if $v = X^2Y, u = X^3Z, \gcd(u,v) = X^2$, then $u$ does not divide $v$ and thus $\frac{u}{\gcd(u,v)}$ does not divide in general $\frac{v}{\gcd(u,v)}$. In case of integers, for $p$ prime, then $p|ab \implies p|a $ or $p|b$. I do not know if one can apply this in case of monomials in a polynomial ring in many variables. The question is, can it occur that $\frac{u}{\gcd(u,v)}$ divides the product $w\cdot v$ but does not divide $w$ ? Normally it can not occur because it will contradict the result that I have to prove. But I do not see how to prove this. Can somebody prove the assertion above or complete my proof ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \tilde u = u / \gcd(u,v)$ and $\tilde v = u / \gcd(u,v)$.

Notice that $\gcd (\tilde u, \tilde v) = 1$. Indeed, if there is some monomial $m$ dividing $\tilde u$ and $\tilde v$, than $m \cdot \gcd(u,v)$ is "greater" than the gcd, contradiction.

Now, what your assertion says is that
$$
\tilde u \mid w \cdot \tilde v \implies \tilde u \mid w 
$$
for any polynomial $w$. Indeed, you can write any polynomial as a linear combination of monomials
$
w = \sum_I a_I x^I
$
and, therefore, $$w \cdot \tilde v = \sum_I a_I (x^I \cdot \tilde v).$$ Now notice that $ \tilde u$ divides $ w \cdot \tilde v$ iff $\tilde u$ divides every monomial. So, we have
$$
\tilde u \mid x^I \cdot \tilde v
$$
for every multi-index I. Since $\gcd(\tilde u, \tilde v) = 1$ we have $\tilde u \mid x^I$ for every $I$ and, therefore, divides $w$.